# problema con autocomplete Jquery-ui

Tags: php, jquery, autocompletar

estoy con un problema con el plug-in autocomplete de jquery-ui en codeigniter.
Para empezar a contarles mi problema debo decir que soy un entusiasta en el tema de la programación, muy novato. y estoy siguiendo un tutorial para la creación de un sistema de ventas y control de stock. Dicho esto les explico lo q me gustaría hacer, en mi vista ventas en el campo productos quiero que al escribir 2 letras se active el plu-gin auto complete. creo que el código esta hecho como se me indicó pero por algún motivo no estoy consiguiendo el resultado q busco, mi codigo es el siguiente..

**ESTE ES EL INPUT EN LA VISTA**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="">Producto:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producto">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="">&nbsp;</label>
    <button id="btn-agregar" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-flat btn-block"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Agregar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CONFIGURACION DEL PLUG-IN**

```
$("#producto").autocomplete({
    source:function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url+"movimientos/ventas/getproductos",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{ valor: request.term},
            success:function(data){
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength:2,
    select: function(event, ui){
        data = ui.item.id_producto +"*"+ ui.item.codigo_producto +"*"+ ui.item.nombre_producto +"*"+ ui.item.precio_producto +"*"+ ui.item.stock_producto;
        $("#btn-agregar").val(data);
    },
});
```

**FUNCION GETPRODUCTO DEL CONTROLADOR**

```
public function getproductos()
{
    //alert("entro en el controlador");
    $valor = $this->input->post("valor"); //CAPTURA LA VARIABLE Q SE ESTA ENVIANDO;
    $clientes = $this->Ventas_models->getproductos($valor); //ALMACENA LO QUE SE RECIBE DEL MODELO GETPRODUCTOS
    echo json_encode($clientes);
}
```

**FUNCION GET PRODUCTO DEL MODELO**

```
    public function getproductos($valor)
{
    //alert("entro en model");
    $this->db->select("id_producto,codigo_producto,nombre_producto,precio_producto,stock_producto");
    $this->db->from("productos");
    $this->db->like("nombre_producto",$valor);
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    //var_dump($resultados);
    return $resultados->result_array();
}
```

Espero alguno pueda darme una mano. Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: En tu función **getproductos()** tienes la siguiente linea que tiene error de sintaxis: **$resultados = $dthis->b->get();** ¿La tienes así en tu código o ha sido cosa de transcribirla aquí?

Comment: gracias por el comentario, amigo, pero fue un error a la hora de transcribir nada mas.. sigue sin funcionar.. aparece una lista debajo del campo pero vacia.. saludos!!

Comment: verifica por consola que trae tu peticion ajax

Comment: success:function(data){ console.log(data);
                response(data);
            }............con eso te mostrara que traes desde tu consulta a php

Comment: Que útil!! no conocía esa herramienta. hice la consulta y no me estira ningún dato, estoy mirando mi código, pero no consigo encontrar donde puede estar mi error. gracias x la guía amigo!! saludos!!

Comment: Mirá que dato estás recibiendo en la función getProductos, así:
$valor = $this->input->post("valor");
print_r($valor)};
die();

y podrías luego ver si le llega a tu función getProductos pero del modelo, haciendo lo mismo 
print_r($valor)};
die();

Comment: cuando agrego esas lineas a mi codigo ya no se activa el autocomplete, antes se desplegaba el espacio para la lista pero vacia.. eso quiere decir que no esta llegando nada a mi controlador??

Comment: Es correcto que no te despliegue ahora información, porque no con el die(); estás finalizando en esa parte del código y no hay ningún return

Haz lo siguiente: abrí la herramienta de desarrollador del navegador (F12) y opción de network, escribí en tu input de buscar y entonces ahí te mostrará las peticiones que se realizan clic sobre alguna petición, luego en response, antepone un echo 'PRUEBA' antes del printr_r para que ver que si te estás respondiendo tu php

PS: si antes te deplegaba la lista vacía entonces si te devuelve datos solo que no los estás mostrando con el nombre que vienen

Comment: wow, cuantas herramientas q no conocía!! efectivamente en la herramienta del desarrollador en red se ve q GETPRODUCTOS obtiene como respuesta lo q busco, osea al escribir azúcar x ejemplo aparecen todos los registros con la palabra azúcar.. Gracias x el apoyo amigo, pero podrías indicarme cual podría ser mi falla en ese caso?

Comment: podría ser q el **select** del plug-in tal vez sea el que este mal configurado?? osea en cual configuración el despliega la lista de coincidencias q encuentra??

Comment: por alguna razon, el campo imput tiene q estar definido como label, le puse --nombre_producto as label-- en el modelo y en vez de llamar nombre_producto en la configuracion del plug-in llame directo label y me funciono.. LABEL es aparentemente una funcion definida del auto complete??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por alguna razón, el campo input tiene q estar definido como label, le puse `nombre_producto as label` en el modelo y en vez de llamar `nombre_producto` en la configuración del plug-in llame directo `label` y me funciono.. LABEL es aparentemente una funcion definida del auto complete??

Comment: No, lo que sucede es que por alguna razón, necesitas darle un as (alias) a tus campos en el select, justo eso te iba a indicar ahorita, que lo que te hacía falta entonces era agregar en tu consulta nombre_producto as nombre_producto y lo mismo para cada campo del select, por alguna razón la cual desconozco te obliga a definirle un alias.

Prueba darle un as a cada campo y de esa manera solucionar tu inconveniente, no es necesario label

PS:lo que puede suceder es que tu consulta esté devolviendo un nombre x y por eso te obliga el alias para crear un objeto json:
{nombre_producto: "x",...}

Comment: excelente!! muchísimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

> Aquí te muestro un ejemplo

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                  var ValoresAutocompletar = [
                        "ARGENTINA",
                            "ARGELIA",
                            "PERU",
                            "BRASIL",
                            "POLONIA"
                    ];

                  $("#autocom").autocomplete({
                  source: ValoresAutocompletar

                  })

            })

    </script>



 <form>
                        <label for="autocom"><strong>NIVEL</strong></label>

                            <input type="text" size="25"  id="autocom" placeholder="Escribe" class="form-control">

                        </form>
```